# Lower values inside $in for PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo, tolower

I want to "lower" the match values inside an "$in". Is there a way to do that?

My code:

```
    results = list(
        col.aggregate([
            {
                '$match': { 'website': { '$in': filters['website'].split('|') }, 'val': { '$ne': None },
            'val': { '$ne': 'none' }}
            }, {
                '$group': {
                    '_id': {
                        'val': $val
                    }
                }
            }, {
                '$project': {
                    '_id': 0,
                    'val': '$_id.val'
                }
            }, {
                '$sort': {
                    'val': 1
                }
            }
        ])
    )

    return dumps(results, indent=4)
```

The filters['website'] can be multiple and are selected on the front end. I want the match to be in LOWER. The values inside the collection now look as so:

- Google
- FaceBook
- Twitter

But I want to lower and match these values. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Since you want to do a case-insensitive search, you have one of two options: 1. you can use a case-insensitive regex search similar to what Belly Buster answered below (note that you will want to do `'^' + filters['website'] + '$'` to ensure that you don't match substrings), or 2. you can use a [`$toLower`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/) aggregation operator in a `$project` stage before performing your `$match` (e.g. `'website': { '$toLower': '$website' }`). A regex search may be better since it will limit your aggregation pipeline size.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a `$regex` with case insensitive switched on. It isn't matching on "lower" but I suspect this is what you are looking for. Also I've refactored your code to use `$nin` which is a bit nicer.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
import re

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

filters = {'website': 'Google|FaceBook|Twitter'}
db.col.insert_one({'website': 'GOOGLE', 'val': 1})
db.col.insert_one({'website': 'Google', 'val': 2})
db.col.insert_one({'website': 'google', 'val': 3})
db.col.insert_one({'website': 'GoOgLe', 'val': 4})
db.col.insert_one({'website': 'FaceBook', 'val': 5})
db.col.insert_one({'website': 'FaceBook', 'val': None})
db.col.insert_one({'website': 'Twitter', 'val': 6})
db.col.insert_one({'website': 'TWITTER', 'val': 7})
db.col.insert_one({'website': 'TWITTER', 'val': 'none'})
db.col.insert_one({'website': 'Instagram', 'val': 8})

results = list(
    db.col.aggregate([
        {
            '$match': {'website': re.compile(filters['website'], re.IGNORECASE), 'val': {'$nin': [ None, 'none' ] }}
        }, {
            '$group': {
                '_id': {
                    'val': '$val'
                }
            }
        }, {
            '$project': {
                '_id': 0,
                'val': '$_id.val'
            }
        }, {
            '$sort': {
                'val': 1
            }
        }
    ])
)

print (json.dumps(results, indent=4))
```

Comment: When I do `#re.compile(filters['website'].split('|'), re.IGNORECASE)` I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: Just put the values in a string and then use `re.compile(filters['website'], ...` as per my example above.